# Making mouse click copy paste to work in all listviews

Tags: c#, listview, copy, paste

I've been programming an application with C#. The app has multiple listviews and I'd like to make it possible to copy text  from any of them with as little code as possible. Currently my copy menu only works with one of the listviews. Here is my code:

Code to copy data:

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //ListView listView = sender as ListView; <---- this didnt work
    if (listViewOrders.SelectedItems.Count >= 1)
    {
        Clipboard.Clear();
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        // Build the data row by row
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listViewOrders.SelectedItems)
        {
            buffer.Append(item.SubItems[0].Text.ToString());
            buffer.Append("\n");
        }
        Clipboard.SetText(buffer.ToString());
    }
}
```

Code to create copy menu when clicked:

```
private void listViewOrders_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = sender as ListView;

    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ListViewItem item = listView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);

        if (item != null)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(listView, e.Location);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `listViewOrders_MouseClick` assign the listview to `contextMenuStrip1.Tag`:

```
private void listViewOrders_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = sender as ListView;

    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ListViewItem item = listView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);

        if (item != null)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
            contextMenuStrip1.Tag = listView;
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(listView, e.Location);
        }
    }
}
```

and then get it back in `toolStripMenuItem1_Click`:

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = (sender as ToolStripItem).Owner.Tag as ListView;
    //ListView listView = (sender as Control).Tag as ListView;
    if (listViewOrders.SelectedItems.Count >= 1)
    {
        ...
```

Comment: Now I getAn unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DynOstoConf.exe

Comment: Should be fixed - but if not, please include the stacktrace for the exception as well :-)